# Using UserManager to change the email of a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to implement a feature to change the email of a user. Asp net core identity by default allows the user to change an email however it requires a confirmation link. I was wondering if it was possible to not use the confirmation link and just edit the function to update the email of the user with the new email. Thanks in advance

I have tried doing

```
 await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, Input.NewEmail, code);
```

and

```
var changingser = _userManager.Users.First(u => u.Email.Equals(email));
changingser.Email = Input.NewEmail;
```

Which did not seem to work

### Email.cshtml: Change Email function

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostChangeEmailAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await LoadAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }

        var email = await _userManager.GetEmailAsync(user);
        if (Input.NewEmail != email)
        {
            var userId = await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user);
            var code = await _userManager.GenerateChangeEmailTokenAsync(user, Input.NewEmail);
            code = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(code));

            await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync(user, Input.NewEmail, code);

/*                var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
                    "/Account/ConfirmEmailChange",
                    pageHandler: null,
                    values: new { userId = userId, email = Input.NewEmail, code = code },
                    protocol: Request.Scheme);*/

                //await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(
                //    Input.NewEmail,
                //    "Confirm your email",
                //    $"Please confirm your account by <a href='{HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(callbackUrl)}'>clicking here</a>.");

            StatusMessage = "Email has been changed";
            return RedirectToPage();
        }

        StatusMessage = "Your email is unchanged.";
        return RedirectToPage();
    }
```

### Edit: Failed invalid token?

[image]

Comment: The latter won't work because of the password hash. You'll have to use the usermanager class

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am trying to use the userManager class and doing .ChangeEmailAsycn but it does not seem to save the change

Comment: See what your return is. Get the IdentityResult from the await _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync call (ie: var result = _userManager.ChangeEmailAsync())

Comment: @GHDevOps I seem to be getting an invalid token for some reason. I have updated the post to show this. Not sure why it's invalid

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @GHDevOps it says InvalidToken

Comment: Try not to encode it. Send the token directly to the reset method (comment out the Base64UrlEncoder and run it)

Comment: @GHDevOps I did this and it changed the email but it doesn't actually change it. The user email on the website appears the old one and you can only login with the old email and not the new one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Use SetEmailAsync to see the `user` email.
This will still require the email to be 'confirmed' so generate a token, then immediately confirm the new email address.

Something like:

```
await _userManager.SetEmailAsync(user, Input.NewEmail);

var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(existingUser);

await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(existingUser, token);
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much

Comment: Great, it's only way I found to set E-mail confirmed without email flow.